# Prevent UISegmentedControl segment selection on focus on tvOS

Tags: focus, selection, uisegmentedcontrol, tvos

I'm working on a simple UI on a tvOS app and I'm facing a strange problem.

When a `UISegmentedControl` get focused you can move your focus around and it automatically changes the selected segment. But what I'm looking for is a way to limit the segment selection only when the user taps the segment, not when he focused it.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry to add a dreaded "me too" comment but like you I need a way to navigate around a UISegmentedControl without actually selecting, selecting on click. Needs to be an option for this control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your own internal variable for the selected segment and only change its value when the select button is pressed (which you can get using a gesture recognizer).   When the segment loses focus (detectable in didUpdateFocus function) you assign the value of your internal variable to the selected index of the segment control.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. Indeed, the change of selection happens after the loss of focus (about a second or so). So when you manually set the selection in the `didUpdateFocus` it lasts about a second or so, then changes again to be automatically set on the focused segment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass UISegmentedControl then override didUpdateFocusInContext. In the "Custom Class" field in IB use the name of your custom class.

Comment: A good guess, but UISegmentedControl acts like a single element, not a group of element at the time of this writing (tvOS 13), and so will not trigger focus update events for segment changes.

Comment: my answer was from 3 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UISegmentedControl and disable the behavior by defining:

```
@objc func _selectFocusedSegment(){
    print ("select focused segment")
}
```

Beware that this solution is a hack. As far as I know there is no good, clean way to accomplish what you want short of steering clear of UISegmentedControl.

Also know that when a UISegmentedControl 'changes focus' between segments, it does not actually change focus. So hooking into focus updates like Nostradamus is suggesting will not work. To the focus engine UISegmentedControl behaves like a single large focusable element, not like a group of focusable segments. You can see this for yourself by debug inspecting a UIFocusUpdateContext on focusing towards or away from a UISegmentedControl.

I stumbled onto _selectFocusedSegment by defining a UISegmentedControl subclass and debug logging the various NSObject.perform methods, among others. My intent was to reverse engineer how UISegmentedControl retains a sticky last focused item, which is quite difficult to do on Apple TV. I was not able to find out exactly how UISegmentedControl manages focus, but I was able to find the answer to your question along the way.